# How to distribute a vector of n elements across p processors

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

Suppose I have a vector of n elements, and I want to distribute it on p processes, where n isn't necessary a multiple of p. Each process has a rank from 0 to p-1. How to determine how many elements will be on each process, to have data distributed the more evenly possible?

For example, if n=14 and p=4, I want a distribution like [3, 3, 4, 4] or [3, 4, 3, 4], but not [3, 3, 3, 5] nor [4, 4, 4, 2].

I want a function f(n, p, r) that returns me the number of elements for process with rank r.

Comment: How about a classic farmer/workers approach? MPI example: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/ppls/farm.c

Comment: Not for my case. I need to distribute rows from an image for processing, so a farmer/worker approach wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: From the problem statement above, you don't know in advance the execution time because this depends on the data, so one farmer, many workers (aka 'bag of tasks') approach seems to be an ideal solution and yes, you can take each row from a matrix and run it on separate processor. A sample of your code would shed more light on the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does

```
(n + r) / p
```

work for you?

Comment: Wow! Even simpler that what I expected.

Comment: This is the single best thing I've learned from reading Stack Overflow.   I'm amazed I haven't seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a special case of the [Bin Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) problem.  There are some very good approximation algorithms, but in theory it is NP-hard.

If you can't be bothered to read the wiki page, I'll cut it down into a few lines.  If you want to look deeper for possibly better solutions, or for an analysis on how well the approximation schemes work, by all means.

Step 1: sort the elements by priority.
Step 2: grab the element with highest priority, and shove it on the least burdened process.
Step 3: If you have more elements, go to Step 1.  Else return.

Comment: No, I know there is a solution to my problem. I just don't remember what it is.